# how to silently guarantee executing an ASP.NET MVC3 action on page unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to execute an action of a controller when a user leave a page (close, refresh, go to link, etc.). The action code is like:

```cs
public ActionResult WindowUnload(int token)
    {
        MyObjects[token].Dispose();
        return Content("Disposed");
    }
```

On window download I do `Ajax` request to the action:

```js
$(window).unload(function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("WindowUnload")",
        data: {token: "@ViewData["Token"]"},
        cache: false,
        async: true
    });
    //alert("Disposing.");
})
```

The above `ajax` request does not come to my controller, i.e., the action is not executed.
To make the code above to work I have to uncomment the `alert` line, but I don't want to fire alert on a user.

If I change `async` option to `false` (`alert` is commented), then it sometimes works. For example, if I refresh the page several times too fast then the action will not be executed for every unload.

Any suggestions how to execute the action on every unload without alert?
Note, I don't need to return anything from action to the page.

### Updated: answers summary

It is not possible reliably to do request on unload, since it is not proper or expected behavior on unload. So it is better to redesign the application and avoid doing HTTP request on window unload.
If it is not avoidable, then there are common solutions (described in the question):

1. Call `ajax` synchronously, i.e., `async: false`.

   - Pros: works in most cases.
   - Pros: silent
   - Cons: does not work in some cases, e.g, when a user refreshes the windows several times too fast (observed in Firefox)
2. Use `alert` on `success` or after `ajax` call

   - Pros: seems to work in all cases.
   - Cons: is not silent and fires pop up alert.

Comment: What are you tring to achieve? There may be a better/ more robust way of getting to your end goal than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wont work and even if you are able to somehow make it work it will give you lots of headaches later on, because this is not how the browser/HTTP is supposed to be used. When the page is unloading (in browser) the browser will call the unload event and then unload the page (you cannot make it wait, not even my making sync ajax calls) and in case the call was going on and the browser after executing the code unload the page, the call will also get cancelled and thats why you see the call on server sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work. If you could tell use why you want to do this we could suggest you a better approach.

Comment: You are right, I don't need to call back to the page. So if there is another solution to call an action it will great.

Answer (score 3):

According to [`unload`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) documentation, with **`async: false`** it should work as expected. However, this will always be a bit shaky - for example, user can leave your page by killing/crashing the browser and you will not receive any callback. Also, browser implementations vary. I fear you won't get any failproof even.

Comment: I experimented with **async: false** and it does not work in all cases. E.g., it does not work when I hit F5 several times too fast.

Comment: As I said, nothing (non-hacky) will really work in that scenario.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP is stateless and you can never get a reliable way to detect that the user has left your page.

Suggested events:

- Session timeout (if you are using sessions)
- The application is going down
- A timer (need to be combined with the previous suggestion)
- Remove the previous token when a new page is visited.

Comment: Using timeouts is in consideration in parallel with unload, but unload is preferable solution for the cases when it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **onbeforeunload()**?

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() 
    { 
        alert('unloading!'); 
    } 
);
```

or

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    alert('unloading!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does this need to happen at all?

From the code snippet you posted you are attempting to use this to dispose of objects server side? You are supposed to call Dispose to [free up any un-managed resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) your objects are using (such as Database connections).

This should be done during the processing of each request. There shouldn't be any un-managed resources awaiting a dispose when the client closes the browser window.

If this is the way you are attempting this in the manner noted above the code needs to be reworked.

Comment: The web page, which is monitored for unload, edits data, so two scenarios possible: either don't allow change of the data on server  while the user updates them (which I try to do), or don't allow to submit changes if data were updated on the server (currently, we don't consider this solution).

Answer (score 1):

From the comment you made to @Frazzell's answer it sounds like you are trying to manage concurrency. So on the chance that this is the case here are two common method for managing it.

### Optimistic concurrency

Optimistic concurrency adds a timestamp to the table. When the client edits the record the timestamp is included in the form.  When they post their update the timestamp is also sent and the value is checked to make sure it is the most recent in the table. If it is, the update succeeds. If it is not then someone else got in sooner with an update so it is discarded. How you handle this is then up to you.

### Pessimistic concurrency

If you often experience concurrency clashes then pessimistic concurrency may be better. Here when the client edits the record a flag is set on that row to lock it. This will remain until the client completes the edit and no other user can edit that row. This method avoids users loosing changes but add an administration over head to the application. Now you need a way to release unwanted locks. You also have to inform the user through the UI that a row is locked for edit.

In my experience it is best to start with optimistic concurrency. If I have lots of people reporting problems I will try to find out why people are having these conflicts. It maybe that I have to break down some entities in to smaller types as they have become responsible for doing too many jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only thing you can do is prompt the user to stay and hope for the best. There are a whole host of security concerns here.